# Matrix logarithm of sum

Tags: matrices, logarithms

Let $D$ be a diagonal, $n\times n$ complex matrix, and let $X$ be an $n\times n$ complex matrix.  Is there is simple formula for
\begin{align}
  \log(D + \epsilon X)
\end{align}
as a power series in $\epsilon$ about $\epsilon = 0$?

Comment: I am not aware of such a formula, but the answer is clearly "not always", e.g. consider the scalar case with $D=0$. Yet you may try the [BCH formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula) and googled for the conditions of convergence.

Comment: If the eigenvalues of $D$ have positive real parts, then for sufficiently large $m>0$, you may also write $\log(D+\epsilon X)$ as $(\log m)I + \log(\frac{D}{m}+\epsilon \frac{X}{m})$ and evaluate the second logarithm with the expansion $\log A = -\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(I-A)^k}{k}$. With luck, you may be able to interchange the order of the double sum and come up with a series expansion. But these are just some rough ideas that may or may not work.

Comment: @user1551 Thanks for the ideas.  I'll let you know if I come up with something.

Comment: Simple not, but [Steve Adler's notes linked here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3174833/362193)...