# Operator expansion for $\ln(A+tB)$

Tags: linear-algebra, logarithms, hilbert-spaces, matrix-calculus, quantum-mechanics

> Expand the following function around $t=0$ $$t \mapsto\ln(A - tB)$$ where $A$ and $B$ are non-commuting finite-dimensional operators over a Hilbert space.

---

I would like to do something in the lines of

$$\ln(a-tb)=\ln(a)+\ln(1-bt/a)$$

and use the Taylor series for $\ln(1-x)$. This doesn't seem trivial for me in the matrix valued case but I thought it might be feasible by means of some Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff like expansion.

It might also help to provide further assumptions given the general context. I have a time-evolved  state

$$\rho'=e^{-tH}\rho e^{+tH}$$

where $H$ is a self-adjoint operator. Since $t \ll 1$, $\rho' \approx \rho -i t [ H, \rho ]$. Then, I want to compute (general case)

$$\ln[e^{-tH} \rho e^{+tH}]$$

So, if either a formula for  the general case would  help or if assuming that $A$ is a state $\rho^\dagger = \rho$ with $\text{Tr}{\rho} = 1$ could give any improvement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2094319/expansion-of-logarithmic-matrix

Comment: Are you happy with [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3174833/362193)?

Comment: Yes! I ended up working with  Adler's expansion https://www.sns.ias.edu/sites/default/files/files/1-matrixlog_tex(1).pdf 

I agree with the edits, obrigado @RodrigodeAzevedo